# Angular 7: How to re-validate control when a property of the model changes

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have a template-driven form which has an input control that I need to validate using a custom validator against the value of a property in my model (which changes dynamically based on a selection from a drop down list). It works fine whenever I type in the input control but I'd like the validation to happen also when the value of the property changes (without having to change the value in the input box). Is there a way to achieve that??

Below is a cut down version of the model, markup and the validator I'm using

Model:

```
 amountToInvest: number = null;
 public onAccountSelectionChanged(event): void {     
    // find the account based on the selection from this drop down list
    this.availableFunds = account.AvailableFunds;
  }
```

Markup

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="myForm.form.valid && onSubmit()" >
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="amountToInvest"' [customMax]="availableFunds">
```

Validator

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[customMax][formControlName],[customMax][formControl],[customMax][ngModel]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: CustomMaxDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class CustomMaxDirective implements Validator {
  @Input()
  customMax: number;

  validate(c: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} {
      let v = c.value;
      return ( v > this.customMax)? {"customMax": true} : null;
  }
```

Comment: I have the same question.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem with a custom validator when the bound value changes without user input

Answer (score 0):

What I did was dispatch an event manually

```
   const event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true, cancelable: false }); //Create an event
   let siblingInput = ele.parentNode['previousElementSibling']['firstChild'] as HTMLInputElement; //Get the element
   siblingInput.dispatchEvent(event); //Dispatch event
```

This will revalidate the control

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am updating the list that I am validating on from an API.  This means the list updates way after the validate call is done.

This code appears to work correctly and it also does not issue a value changed warning on the ngvalid flag:

```js
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator } from '@angular/forms';
import { some } from 'lodash';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMissing]',
  providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: MissingDirective, multi: true }],
})
export class MissingDirective implements Validator {
  //  This little bit of trickery should retrigger validation when the list is reloaded
  private storeList: string[];
  @Input()
  get list() {
    return this.storeList;
  }
  set list(codes: string[]) {
    this.storeList = codes;
    console.log('rechecking', this.ctrl?.value, this.list);
    if (this.ctrl) {
      this.ctrl.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });
    }
  }

  ctrl?: FormControl;

  validate(c: FormControl): { [key: string]: any } {
    this.ctrl = c;
    if (c.value && this.list) {
      const v = c.value.toUpperCase();
      if (!some(this.list, x => x && x.toUpperCase() === v)) {
        return { appMissing: true };
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```